# Searching for strings in files using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have something like

```
set @file = 'aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,eeee,ffff'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@file,CHARINDEX(',',@file)+1, CHARINDEX(',',@file,CHARINDEX(',',@file)+1) -CHARINDEX(',',@file)-1) as My_string
```

This will print out

```
     My_string
    ----------------
   1|     bbbb
```

How could I make it print?

```
   My_string
 ------------
1|   bbbb
2|   cccc
3|   dddd
4|   eeee
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.,(Refered from [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows))

```
declare @file varchar(max)
set @file = 'aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,eeee,ffff'

;with tmp(DataItem, Data) 
as (
select LEFT(@file, CHARINDEX(',',@file+',')-1),
    STUFF(@file, 1, CHARINDEX(',',@file+','), '')
union all
select LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1),
    STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
from tmp
where Data > '')
select DataItem from tmp
```

Comment: I must ask something that I am curious about,is there a way to say something like `set @file = 'aaa,2,1,bbb,3,2,ccc,1,ddd,2,eee,3,2'`,is there a way to place `aaa&bbb&ccc&ddd&eee` as first_column `2&3&1&2&3`as second_column and `1&2&NULL&NULL&2`as third_column? And I am asking for this specific example not for others that would be string string int or int int string,I am asking for this example where you have string,int,int

Comment: Yes but the inclusion of optional columns complicates matters.  If you can spec out the rules, perhaps in a new question, I'm sure we can come up with something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238242/read-char-double-int-pattern-from-string-in-sql

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the [Split string functions](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) ..I used below function..

```
declare @file nvarchar(max)
set @file = 'aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,eeee,ffff'

select row_number() over (order by (select  null)) as number,b.*
from
[dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](@file,',') b
```

**Output:**

```
number  Item
1   aaaa
2   bbbb
3   cccc
4   dddd
5   eeee
6   ffff
```

**split string source code i used for Completeness:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers
    (
       @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
       @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
       RETURN
       (
           SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
             CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
           FROM dbo.Numbers
           WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
             AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
       );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way using XML.

Test Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (StringName varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #TestData (StringName) 
VALUES ('aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,eeee,ffff')
```

Query

```
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
FROM  (SELECT [StringName],  
        CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(StringName, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  #TestData) AS A 
CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Result

```
String
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
ffff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @file varchar(255)
SET @file = 'aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd,eeee,ffff'
DECLARE @X xml
DECLARE @Split char(1) = ','
SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@file,@Split,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>') 

SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
```

Output

```
Value
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
ffff
```